# How to iterate on all days between start and end date in Python

Tags: python, loops, datetime

Using Python, I'm calling from a function that requires a Day, Month & Year input.

**Objective**

I'm pulling in Basketball data, which runs from October to April so there's plenty of data per day. I would like to be able to iterate through each day / month and year from 1st October 2013 to 1st August 2020.

```
client.team_box_scores(
    day=, month=2, year=2017, 
    output_type=OutputType.CSV, 
    output_file_path="./1_1_2017_box_scores.csv"
)
```

**Initial Research**

From researching I've found the *datetime* module as well as a *for loop* that I could leverage, but in terms of embedding those into the above function I really don't know how to do that.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Dear @Graham, could you describe the question more clearly? what is your objective? add code if possible

Comment: @Graham, could you write more about what you are going to do? Are you going to input two dates and iterate all dates between those two dates?

Comment: @AvivYaniv / @ Yuri Ren 

I've updated the description. Hopefully that's sufficient. Apologies if not, I'm not experienced enough to articulate exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 7):

```
import datetime

start_date = datetime.date(year=2013, month=10, day=1)
end_date   = datetime.date(year=2020, month=8,  day=1)

current_date = start_date
# Iterating over all dates from start date until end date including end date ("inclusive")
while current_date <= end_date:
    # Calling the function that you need, with the appropriate day-month-year combination
    # Outputting to path that is build based on current day-month-year combination
    client.team_box_scores(
        day=current_date.day, month=current_date.month, year=current_date.year,
        output_type=OutputType.CSV,
        output_file_path=f"./{current_date.day}_{current_date.month}_{current_date.year}_box_scores.csv"
    )
    # Advancing current date by one day
    current_date += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

Answer (score -1):

if you want to run a loop that creates day, month, and year there is something that you must be aware of!
1- leap years. (adds one day to the February)
2- month days are not the same.
3- you must make it maintainable!

so here is my solution:

```
def leap_year(this_year):
    if (this_year % 4) == 0:
        if (this_year % 100) == 0:
            if (this_year % 400) == 0:
                return True

    return False


for my_year in range(2020, 2100 + 1):
    print(my_year)
    year_months = {
        1: 31,
        2: 29 if leap_year(my_year) else 28,
        3: 31,
        4: 30,
        5: 31,
        6: 30,
        7: 31,
        8: 31,
        9: 30,
        10: 31,
        11: 30,
        12: 31,
    }
    for my_month in year_months.keys():
        day = year_months[my_month]
        for my_day in range(1, day + 1):
            print("year = {0}, month: {1}, day: {2}".format(my_year, my_month, my_day))
```

!!! that +1 in range(2020, 2100 + 1) is there because range() function always calculates lower band of the range.
Hope you have good days.